# Ubuntu 15.04 system freeze while removing USB 3.0 device from Express card

Tags: 15.04, hibernate, crash, expresscard

I have the following Express card which provides USB 3.0 host  controller.

05:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02)

The express card works fine under Win7 , win 10 and 
Ubuntu 14.04 . Under 15.04 the system freezes randomly while

1. Removing the express card.
2. Removing a USB device connected to it .
3. Resuming the system from hibernation .

It is particularly bothersome as these freezes are causing frequent fsck checks and corrupted files , caused by having to force reboot the system .

My laptop is the HP DV6T-2000 CT0 model with the  Core i7-720QM CPU .Are there any work arounds or temporary solutions which i can try ?

lspci gives the following output :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DMI (rev 11)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 11)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Management Registers (rev 11)
00:08.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor Semaphore and Scratchpad Registers (rev 11)
00:08.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Control and Status Registers (rev 11)
00:08.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor Miscellaneous Registers (rev 11)
00:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link (rev 11)
00:10.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Routing and Protocol Registers (rev 11)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 05)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 230M] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GT216 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
04:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller
04:00.1 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller
04:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller
04:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller
04:00.4 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. xD Host Controller
05:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-Core Registers (rev 04)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 04)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 04)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 04)
ff:03.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller (rev 04)
ff:03.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Target Address Decoder (rev 04)
ff:03.4 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers (rev 04)
ff:04.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Control Registers (rev 04)
ff:04.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Address Registers (rev 04)
ff:04.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Rank Registers (rev 04)
ff:04.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Thermal Control Registers (rev 04)
ff:05.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Control Registers (rev 04)
ff:05.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Address Registers (rev 04)
ff:05.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Rank Registers (rev 04)
ff:05.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Thermal Control Registers (rev 04)
```

uname -a gives the follwing

```
Linux quaddy 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04LTS with kernel 3.13 or 3.19

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going through the instructions in this [Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/999462). On one lenovo thinkpad I tested the uPD720202 stops creating intermittent freezing after disabling the PCIe power management in the bios. Other workarounds are suggested in that bug report with varying results